# how to restrict the autocomplete div tags height without affecting the following field

Tags: html, css

[![How to restrict the autocomplete div tags height without affecting the bottom fields.
Here when i'm searching for country references dropdown is showing, but the entire height is increasing.
here the dropdown is fall over the communication field. How to achieve this. Please find the PIC for better understanding Thanks.`
Country Reference

```
  <div class="form-group right">
    <label for="Communication_Type" class="label-title">Communication Type</label>
      <div class="autocomplete1">
        <input type="text" class="" id="empid1" name="empid1">
        <div class="dialog1">
          <ul id="charactersList1"></ul>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

.cref_container {
background-color: yellow;
}
.label_cref {
display: inline-block;
margin-left: 25px;
padding: 5px;
width: 30%;
margin-top: 2px;
background-color: royalblue;
}
.autocomplete {
/* background: #fff; */
position: relative;
}
.autocomplete .close {
position: absolute;
font-size: 13px;
z-index: 10;
top: 10px;
left: calc(100% - 50px);
color: #aaa;
cursor: pointer;
display: none;
}
.autocomplete .close.visible {
display: block;
}

.dialog {
width: 60%;
margin-left: 40%;
display: none;
min-height: 40px;
max-height: 330px;
overflow: scroll;
border-top: 1px solid #f4f4f4;
}
.dialog.open {
display: block;
}
.dialog div {
padding: 20px 10px;
font-size: 13px;
cursor: pointer;
transition: all 0.2s;
}
.dialog div:hover {
background: #f2f2f2;
}`][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHiuE.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHiuE.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. either use a native "select" input component which already does that (see https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp)
2. set your "dialog1"'s position to "fixed" and set its "left" and "top" from javascript. "fixed" position takes it out of the normal layout and doesn't push around any other elements.

```js
const leftCoordinate = 20;
const topCoordinate = 100;
document.getElementsByClassName("dialog1")[0].style.left = leftCoordinate;
document.getElementsByClassName("dialog1")[0].style.top = topCoordinate;
```

```css
.dialog1 {
  position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Take the position as relative for top of the div and take the position as absolute for another div like dropdown or autocomplete.